# Visual studio 2008 not catching a syntax error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, syntax

Visual studio 2008 isn't catching syntax errors. for example: `Tpc_feed(void);` compiles fine.
this: `Tpc_feed(void);;;;;;;` compiles fine, but this `Tpc_feed(void)` catches an error. Are the extra semi-colons not syntax errors? I'm on Windows 7 32 bit and VS C++ 2008

Comment: grammar rules require the semicolon. consecutive semicolons imply blank lines of code, which are ignored by the compiler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, it's a syntax error, but most compilers allow it anyway. GCC even allows it by default unless you compile with `-pedantic`.

In any case, it's against the standard so you should get rid of the extras.

Comment: I know that I should get rid of them, but why do compilers allow it?

Comment: Who knows? Compilers aren't perfect. It's probably not a high priority to fix because it (1) has no effect on correct programs, and (2) it's easy to guess what the coder's intent was when they type like that.

Answer (score 1):

Without a return type, none of them should compile as C++. Assuming a return type is added, the extra semicolons are allowed on member function declarations, but if the declarations are outside a class/struct they're prohibited.

I don't believe VC++ has a flag to force them to be flagged as errors.

Edit: Actually (going back and re-checking things), an unnecessary semi-colon is allowed following a member function *definition*, but I think you're right, and it's not allowed following a member function *declaration*.

Comment: its my class constructor, so doesn't it compile as C++?

Comment: Oh, okay -- yes a ctor doesn't need to (and in fact, can't) specify a return type. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, it's not a valid C++. The reason why many compilers support it anyway is that it makes creating macros a bit easier/more intuitive, consider this:

```
// Declares a function, and because the semicolon belongs to the declaration, the macro adds it
#define MY_FUNCTION_DECL(returnType, arguments) returnType myFunction arguments;

// Calling macros looks like functions, the semicolon looks natural
MY_FUNCTION_DECL(void, (int, int, int));  // There are two semicolons now
```

This example is somewhat weird as I made it up right now but it should represent the idea behind accepting more semicolons as valid.